# PhpStorm 8.0 - How enable code completion in another file?

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, completion

I implement `MyClass` containing the method `method()` and I store the instance in `$_ENV['key']` in **test.php**. Also in test.php the code completion works when I type `$_ENV['key']->`.

In **test2.php** I include test.php and the code completion does not work any more for `$_ENV['key']->`.

[image]

Does anyone know how to enable this in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK type tracking for arrays works within the same file **only**.

You can bypass it via intermediate variable (yes, it's not a nicest solution) and small PHPDoc comment, like this:

```
/** @var MyClass $myVar */
$myVar = $_ENV['key'];
$myVar->
```

---

**P.S.**
In general, I'd suggest not using global arrays this way (or even not using global vars at all -- only very basic stuff during bootstrap, if possible). Instead (based on your code) I may suggest using some static class (as one of the alternatives) with dedicated field where you can easily give type hint (via PHPDoc) to a class field -- this way IDE will always know hat type it is. Current PHP versions (5.5 and especially 5.6) work with objects nearly as fast as with arrays, even leading in (smaller) memory consumption.

Obviously, such suggestion does not really apply if this code is not yours.

Comment: In fact in my code I use a file "bootstrap.php" and it instantiate classes and I store in $ _ENV. 

For example SwitfMailer: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10455465/

Comment: And also store instances of some singletons. To avoid being all the time using "SingletonClass::getInstance()"

Comment: **1)** I understand that. But ATM PhpStorm cannot work with individual array elements/keys in a same way as it can with individual variables or classes (especially if it's done across multiple files).  With PHPDoc you can easily provide type hint for individual variable or class field/property .. but you cannot do that for individual array element. **2)** *"To avoid being all the time using `SingletonClass::getInstance()`" In my opinion `getInstance()` is actually better as it allows to utilize **lazy loading** -- class is loaded/used only when needed and not on every script invocation.